# Error 1385 when executing RUNAS on Windows Enterprise 7

Tags: windows, permissions, runas

I am having trouble installing an application on a `Windows 7 Enterprise` computer. The installer creates a user under which a service process will run. However I get the code error 1385 all over my logs (installer and installed service). I managed to isolate the problem in such environment. I can reproduce it easily doing:

```
runas /env /user:thehostname\thejustcreatedusername
```

then the `thejustcreatedusername` password is asked, and as result I get:

```
Erreur de RUNAS : Impossible d'exécuter - notepad
1385 - Échec d'ouverture de session : l'utilisateur ne bénéficie pas du type d'ouverture de session demandé sur cet ordinateur.
```

I think it corresponds to the English version: `Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer`.

In the internet I found that I should grant the user the `access this computer from network` right. I did it following the steps at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277404.aspx, through the `Local Security Policy` tool, but no success (still same 1385 error). I also added my user to the `Users` group that has that right already granted but no success. However if I add that user to the Administrators group, the RUNAS command works and I see a notepad being launched.

What setting should I change in such user to run that impersonation command successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need logon as a service right.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed Jon, granting that right and also `Allow log on locally` did the trick.

There is an explanation on the reason why the installer worked on some environments and failed in some other ones. It worked correctly on environments whose Users group had been granted these rights (which is by default I think), and hence the new user inherited such permissions, leading to a non failure situation. 
However in the non-working environment, the Users group had not been granted such right, and hence the newly created user did not inherit, and hence the 1385 error in both installation and during runtime.

Thanks!